# prevent content to overlap margin of sticky header

Tags: css, header, sticky

I have a layout set up like in the snippet below.

I am trying to make a sticky header with `margin-top: 20px;`

I was thinking of a method, that could produce a sticky header, without the content to overlap the top-margin of the sticky header when scrolling down.

In the snipped provided, you can see, that the content overlaps the empty space above the header part. This is what I want to avoid. I want to see 20px of the background image above the header at all times.

The only solution I could come up with, was splitting the whole content into a header div and a body div, and giving both a background, so that the background would still look like one piece.

This is illustrated in the picture given, on the **right side**. 
This is how **I know it can be done**, but to me it feels like this is not the best approach, since I would like to have the content grouped into one div and not into 2 seperate ones.

On **the left side** is what I would like to achive:
The blue part of the content should not be visible, instead, the background picture should be visible. 
And the header should have the desired  `position: sticky; top: 20px;`.

Is this even possible in any other way, or do I have to split up the header and the content into 2 different div`s to achieve this?

[image]

Here`s the snippet to check out the current behaviour:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: Roboto, "Helvetica Neue", sans-serif;
  background-color: darkgray;
  background: url('https://codetheweb.blog/assets/img/posts/css-advanced-background-images/cover.jpg') no-repeat center center fixed;
  background-size: auto;
  background-size: cover;
  min-width: 270px;
  height: auto;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.main {
  
}

.container-box {
  display: block;
  margin: 20px auto;
  padding: 20px;
  background-image: linear-gradient(red 100px, yellow 100px, yellow);
  height: auto;
  max-width: 920px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  box-shadow: 0px 2px 1px -1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0px 1px 1px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.14), 0px 1px 3px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
}

.navigation {
position: sticky;
top: 20px;
background-color: red;
}

.top-navigation {
  text-align: right;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.bot-navigation {
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.content{
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="main">
    <div class=" container-box ">
      <div class="navigation">
        <div class="top-navigation">
          <button>Logout</button>
        </div>
        <div class="bot-navigation">
          SOME NAVIGATION OVER HERE
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="content">
        SOME CONTENT<br> 
        SOME CONTENT<br> 
        SOME CONTENT<br> 
        SOME CONTENT<br> 
        SOME CONTENT<br> 
        SOME CONTENT<br> 
        SOME CONTENT<br> 
        SOME CONTENT<br> 
        SOME CONTENT<br> 
        SOME CONTENT<br> 
        SOME CONTENT<br> 
        SOME CONTENT<br> 
        SOME CONTENT<br> 
        SOME CONTENT<br> 
        SOME CONTENT<br> 
        SOME CONTENT<br> 
        SOME CONTENT<br> 
        SOME CONTENT<br>
        SOME CONTENT<br> 
        SOME CONTENT<br> 
        SOME CONTENT<br> 
        SOME CONTENT<br> 
        SOME CONTENT<br> 
        SOME CONTENT<br> 
        SOME CONTENT<br> 
        SOME CONTENT<br> 
        SOME CONTENT<br> 
        SOME CONTENT<br> 
        SOME CONTENT<br> 
        SOME CONTENT<br> 
        SOME CONTENT<br> 
        SOME CONTENT<br> 
        SOME CONTENT<br> 
        SOME CONTENT<br> 
        SOME CONTENT<br> 
        SOME CONTENT<br>
        SOME CONTENT<br> 
        SOME CONTENT<br> 
        SOME CONTENT<br> 
        SOME CONTENT<br> 
        SOME CONTENT<br> 
        SOME CONTENT<br> 
        SOME CONTENT<br> 
        SOME CONTENT<br> 
        SOME CONTENT<br> 
        SOME CONTENT<br> 
        SOME CONTENT<br> 
        SOME CONTENT<br> 
        SOME CONTENT<br> 
        SOME CONTENT<br> 
        SOME CONTENT<br> 
        SOME CONTENT<br> 
        SOME CONTENT<br> 
        SOME CONTENT<br>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: instead of making the header sticky make the yellow container scrollable

Comment: @ZohirSalak no this is not what i want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can consider a trick with a pseudo element since you are using fixed with background. You apply the same background to the pseudo element and you place it on the top to create the illusion

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: Roboto, "Helvetica Neue", sans-serif;
  background-color: darkgray;
  background: url('https://codetheweb.blog/assets/img/posts/css-advanced-background-images/cover.jpg') no-repeat fixed;
  background-size: cover;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.container-box {
  display: block;
  margin: 20px auto;
  background: yellow;
  border-radius: 10px;
  box-shadow: 0px 2px 1px -1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0px 1px 1px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.14), 0px 1px 3px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
}

.navigation {
  position: sticky;
  top: 40px;
  background-color: red;
  padding:0 20px 20px;
}

/* this will do the magic*/
.navigation:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 100%;
  left: -2px;
  right: -2px;
  height: 40px;
  background: url('https://codetheweb.blog/assets/img/posts/css-advanced-background-images/cover.jpg') no-repeat fixed;
  background-size: cover;
}
/**/
/* for the radius*/
.navigation:after {
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  bottom:100%;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  height:20px;
  background:red;
  border-radius:10px 10px 0 0;
}
/**/

.top-navigation {
  text-align: right;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.bot-navigation {
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.content {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class=" container-box ">
    <div class="navigation">
      <div class="top-navigation">
        <button>Logout</button>
      </div>
      <div class="bot-navigation">
        SOME NAVIGATION OVER HERE
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="content">
      SOME CONTENT<br> SOME CONTENT<br> SOME CONTENT<br> SOME CONTENT<br> SOME CONTENT<br> SOME CONTENT<br> SOME CONTENT<br> SOME CONTENT<br> SOME CONTENT<br> SOME CONTENT<br> SOME CONTENT<br> SOME CONTENT<br> SOME CONTENT<br> SOME CONTENT<br> SOME CONTENT
      <br> SOME CONTENT<br> SOME CONTENT<br> SOME CONTENT<br> SOME CONTENT<br> SOME CONTENT<br> SOME CONTENT<br> SOME CONTENT<br> SOME CONTENT<br> SOME CONTENT<br> SOME CONTENT<br> SOME CONTENT<br> SOME CONTENT<br> SOME CONTENT<br> SOME CONTENT<br> SOME
      CONTENT<br> SOME CONTENT<br> SOME CONTENT<br> SOME CONTENT<br> SOME CONTENT<br> SOME CONTENT<br> SOME CONTENT<br> SOME CONTENT<br> SOME CONTENT<br> SOME CONTENT<br> SOME CONTENT<br> SOME CONTENT<br> SOME CONTENT<br> SOME CONTENT<br> SOME CONTENT
      <br> SOME CONTENT<br> SOME CONTENT<br> SOME CONTENT<br> SOME CONTENT<br> SOME CONTENT<br> SOME CONTENT<br> SOME CONTENT<br> SOME CONTENT<br> SOME CONTENT<br> SOME CONTENT<br>

    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer :)! This is pretty cool, and would work fine for a content without border-raidus. But due to the fact, that we cannot stack the pseudo element below its parent element, if the parent element has position sticky, I can still see the edges of the content where the rounded edges of the navigation element is not overlapping the content div...

Comment: @DigitalJedi what browser are you using? I see nothing on my side

Comment: Chrome, and Firefox both behavethe same. its almost not visible. Its clearly visible if you set .container-box{ border: 1px solid black; } instead of the box shadow. but in both cases, it can be seen unfortunately

Comment: @DigitalJedi check the update, you can use the other pseudo element to hide this